# Compare coordinates in one dataframe with another dataframe (3 columns by 3 columns)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, compare

I have two pandas dataframes. They look like this:

```
df1:

x  y  z  label
1  2 -3   A
4  5 -9   B
3  4  6   C
-1 0  3   no_label
5  6  7   no_label

df2:

x1 y1 z1  label1
1  2 -4   23
2  4 10   56
5  6  6   56
-1 0  3   75
```

The goal is to compare coordinates (three columns in one df and three columns in another) in rows.

Problem 1: they could be the same in different rows.

Problem 2: they were calculated by different algorithms, so coordinates could differ in +/- 1 value.

Problem 3: data frames are different in sizes.

The goal is to compare and in a place in df1 where there is 'no_label' and coordinates match with df2 put the value from df2 from the row where coordinates match.
Output example:

```
x  y  z  label
1  2 -3   A
4  5 -9   B
3  4  6   C
-1 0  3   75
5  6  7   56
```

I tried to convert them into lists but I stuck in a middle...
Does someone have any ideas on how to perform this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a one-line solution to this, and you need to just loop through the dataframes and compare:

```
for i in df1.index:
   if df1.at[i,'label'] == 'no_label':
      for j in df2.index:
         if df2.at[j,'x1']-1 <= df1.at[i,'x'] <= df2.at[j,'x1']+1:
            if df2.at[j,'y1']-1 <= df1.at[i,'y'] <= df2.at[j,'y1']+1:
               if df2.at[j,'z1']-1 <= df1.at[i,'z'] <= df2.at[j,'z1']+1:
                  df1.loc[i,'label'] = df2.at[j,'label1']
                  continue
print(df1)
```

Didn't test the code but I hope you get the idea!